# Automate conversion of variables to Options in Scala

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

This set of variables is convenient   ..

```
var lastName: String = _
var address: Address = _
```

but it sets them to null - a big no-no in scala..

This section below is more scala idiomatic ..

```
var lastName = None: Option[String]
var address = None: Option[Address]
```

but the extra typing is less than optimal.

Any automation out there for Options - to get the best of both scenarios?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `none` method from [`scalaz`](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz):

```
import scalaz.std.option.none

var lastName = none[String]
var address = none[Address]
```

You could write such method by yourself if you don't want to use `scalaz`:

```
def none[T]: Option[T] = None
```

There is also method `some` in `scalaz`, that returns `Option`:

```
import scalaz.syntax.std.option._

1.some
// res0: Option[Int] = Some(1)
```

As [Régis Jean-Gilles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1632462/regis-jean-gilles) [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22032628/automate-conversion-of-variables-to-options-in-scala/22032752?noredirect=1#comment33408365_22032752) there is also `Option.empty`. You could either use it directly:

```
var address = Option.empty[Address]
```

or import it and use like `none` above:

```
import Option.{empty => none}

var address = none[Address]
```

Comment: FWIW note that `none` here is the same as `Option.empty`. You could even just use an alias: `import Option.{empty => none}`. Using a proper method is better though, as it can then be imported as needed in every compilation unit without having to retype the alias.

Answer (score 4):

Does this make you feel better?

```
var lastName: Option[String] = None
var address: Option[Address] = None
```

or

```
object none {
  def apply[T]: Option[T] = None
}
var lastName = none[String]
var address = none[Address]
```